# CA1014 Mark 'some.dll' with CLSCompliant(true) error message with StyleCop of VS2010

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, dll, stylecop, cls-compliant

When I run StyleCop, I got this error message saying that I need to Mark the dll with CLSCompliant(true).

What is this? How can I set the Mark the dll with CLSCompliant(true)?

```
Error   4   CA1014 : Microsoft.Design : 
Mark 'SOMETHING.dll' with CLSCompliant(true) because it exposes externally 
                     visible types. ModelsimCommunicator
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

To mark the DLL as CLS compliant do the following in the root namespace.

```
[assembly: CLSCompliant(true)]
```

Note: This error is coming from FxCop not StyleCop.  FxCop errors are prefixed with CA while StyleCop uses the SA prefix

Comment: Are you sure it's *in* the root namespace, because Microsoft says have it *before* the namespace. (http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev10.query?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(MARKASSEMBLIESWITHCLSCOMPLIANT)%3bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-%22.NETFRAMEWORK%2cVERSION%3dV4.0%22)&rd=true)

Comment: try adding this to AssemblyInfo.cs

Comment: The CA rules are also part of the Code Analysis run when you enable CA for a project.

Comment: Credit to @JaredPar and hnafar for the correct answer. For anyone who might encounter this in a WPF application using .NET 6, I just added [assembly: CLSCompliant(true)] to the AssemblyInfo.cs file that was already part of the project template.

Comment: I would like to know more about why this occurs. I have a solution of around 70 projects and I get this warning on two of them. The same two projects also raise warning CA2210 "Sign 'my.dll' with a strong name key" which may or may not be coincidental. Obviously I can suppress these warnings, but it would be useful to work out why just these two projects are raising these warnings. Anyone have a clue? (VS2022)

Answer (score 1):

To disable:

```
[assembly: CLSCompliant(false)]
```